# Tag synonyms: [fuzzing], [fuzzer], and [fuzz-testing]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[fuzzing](/questions/tagged/fuzzing), [fuzzer](/questions/tagged/fuzzer), and [fuzz-testing](/questions/tagged/fuzz-testing) mean the same thing and should be made into synonyms.

[fuzzing](/questions/tagged/fuzzing) has a tag wiki entry, the others do not.

Comment: This request makes me feel warm and fuzzy!

Comment: @bluefeet don't forget about [tag:fuzzy-logic] logic for that fuzzy feel. Speaking of [tag:fuzzy] things, it wouldn't hurt if someone went though the questions tagged [tag:fuzzy] and disambiguated a bit, there are several uses.